# serial monitor of arduino IDE showing different output

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am accessing ros messages in arduino by serializing it through ros serial. But when i am sending some text from arduino code through  serial it is showing different output in serial monitor of arduino ide. Seems all the text have mixed with some other data .What can be possible reason?Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199817/serial-monitor-of-arduino-ide-showing-different-output/) by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-12-19**:
Please copy and paste both outputs. Could it be that you use const char* in Arduino and String in ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosserial encodes the messages. It does not just send the raw data as when you use serial directly.
That is why you see different things.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-12-19**:
I thought if it send message data then only it encodes it , like in case when we advertise a topic....So does it encode the normal message also before sending it through serial?